# Link to GitHub StackExchange.DataExplorer has incorrect formatting, in Applications profile tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks, data-explorer

In my [applications tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/apps/798831), I noticed that the link to the GitHub StackExchange.DataExplorer had incorrect formatting (the bit where it says [open source]:

[image: ]]

It doesn't actually look like it has incorrect formatting, it just isn't showing up as a hyperlink.

Can we please fix this?

Answer (score 3):

What is shown there is the Description field of a StackApps Application.

That field has the following info message:

> This text-only blurb will be shown to users during authentication.

It is not meant to contain markdown. The description need to be edited by the author of the app (in this case that is also Stack Exchange). No fixes in the code are needed.

Here is what an app of mine shows in my profile:

> [image: markdown visible]

and this is what I entered in the Stack Apps Registration page for that app:

> [image: registration]

It is not a code bug, it is a content bug. Yes, it would be nice if that gets edited.