# Cannot delete a login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, my-logins

I have two email addresses associated with this account. I was trying to remove the previous email. However, the remove button in the "My logins" page did not work.

I thought it was an issue with my browser. I have now tried Brave, Brave with all "protection"s disabled, and Firefox. The button just doesn't work, no matter how hard or frequently I press.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369929/798831

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411533/how-to-remove-multiple-email-ids-from-an-account-and-only-keep-one#comment867753_411533

Comment: True, the "Remove" is just a label, not a button anymore. SE removed the option to remove logins, sadly such bugs can take years until a developer even takes a look.

Comment: We are aware of this issue and our team is working on getting this issue solved as soon as possible and we will update you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience here folks. We've been going through some big frontend overhauls within our codebase, and one of them unexpectedly affected the "Remove Login" functionality. TL/DR: class naming changes within that page disconnected it from its own JS code.

A fix for this issue has been published and we made sure the code changes are compliant with our internal frontend standards so that future changes won't bring this page down again.

Thanks for reporting! We appreciate you folks.

Comment: Looks like this same class mismatch issue [is also happening for the applications tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working); can that please be fixed?